# Is this a syntax error or an error with the compiler?

Tags: arrays, c, printf, declaration

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char charName[] = "John";
    int charAge[] = 35;

    printf("There once was a man named %s\n", charName);
    printf("He was %s\n", charAge); 

    return 0;
}
```

First error: array initializer must be an initializer list or wide string literal
`int charAge[] = 35;`
Second error: make: *** [<builtin>: main.o] Error 1
exit status 2

I did everything I could to fix this, but nothing worked.

Comment: In addition to the answer that's already been provided, you are attempting to print an array of ints as a string. What do you expect this to achieve?

Comment: It's clear that the poster wants `charAge` to be a single integer and is unfamiliar with `printf` semantics.

Comment: You should assume that all problems the compiler reports are problems with your code, not with the compiler.  It is extremely unlikely (though not actually impossible) that you run into a compiler bug.  But it is much, much safer to assume that the problem is yours.

Answer (score 2):

The error comes from the fact that you're declaring an **array** of integers, `int charAge[]` and yet you're assigning not an array but an individual value, `35`, to it.

Based on your usage, you don't want an array.  So, you can just do

```c
int charAge = 35;
```

Furthermore, when you're printing `charAge`, you need to use `%i` (or `%d`; that's also acceptable for integers) instead of `%s`.  `%s` is for `char` arrays like `charName`.  That is, you should do

```c
printf("He was %i\n", charAge);
```

Answer (score 1):

If it was an error of the compiler then it would be already resolved.

If you declare an array then the initializer must be a braced list like

```
int charAge[] = { 35 };
```

The only exception is initialization of character arrays with string literals like

```
char charName[] = "John";
```

that may be also rewritten like

```
char charName[] = { "John" };
```

From the C Standard (6.7.9 Initialization)

> 14 **An array of character type may be initialized by a character string
> literal or UTF−8 string literal, optionally enclosed in braces.**
> Successive bytes of the string literal (including the terminating null
> character if there is room or if the array is of unknown size)
> initialize the elements of the array.
>
> 15 An array with element type compatible with a qualified or
> unqualified version of wchar_t may be initialized by a wide string
> literal, optionally enclosed in braces. Successive wide characters of
> the wide string literal (including the terminating null wide character
> if there is room or if the array is of unknown size) initialize the
> elements of the array.
>
> **16 Otherwise, the initializer for an object that has aggregate or union type shall be a brace-enclosed list of initializers for the
> elements or named members.**

Pay attention to that this call of `printf`

```
printf("He was %s\n", charAge);
```

invokes undefined behavior.

Taking into account the name of the array it seems you was going to declare it with the element type `char` like

```
char charAge[] = "35";
```

Otherwise you need to write

```
printf("He was %d\n", *charAge);
```

In general elements of an array of an integral type (except arrays that contain strings) should be outputted in a loop element by element.

Though in this concrete case there is no sense to declare an array. You could declare just a scalar object

```
int charAge = 35;
```

In this case the call or `printf` will look like

```
printf("He was %d\n", charAge);
```